# Creating a database with authentication enabled on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, authentication, authorization

I can create a database using a specific role for my "user1".
I have tested and a user "test1" can not create a database in the mode authorization enabled.
How works the creation of the database? I created a user "user1" and it can  access this database "db1" only. Can I have the same user "user1" with privileges to create a new database as exists in SQL Server?
I might be (completeley) wrong, but I would like an explanation concrete about this case.
Thank you for any help and instruction. :)

Comment: What does this have to do with MongoDB?

Comment: I did not get your question. The objective is to find a solution how to create a database in mongodb using a user  already authenticated in mode authorization enabled.

Comment: If this is for MongoDB, why did you tag it with SQL Server?

Comment: I am sorry. Just removed it. Thank you.

Comment: Agreed with Brendan, that's why I was confused in my question. You also mentioned SQL Server in your post's body but make no mention of MongoDB. You may want to update your post body by removing the reference to SQL Server and instead puting your objective that you mentioned in your comment above.

Comment: You are correct. Let me clarify because in SQL Server I can create a database after authenticating with a user that is able to see his own database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really hard to understand your question.

Maybe your problem is this: In MongoDB you have different databases. Database `admin`, `config` and `local` are pre-defined system databases.

Users and roles are created in databases, I think that's a quite unique behavior for MongoDB. You can create users and roles in **any** database, however the `admin` database should be the common one.

The `admin` database includes roles for administering the whole system rather than just a single database. These roles are mainly related to replica set and sharded cluster administrative functions.

Roles which are created in **other** database than `admin` can only include privileges that apply to its database and can only inherit from other roles in its database.

A role created in the `admin` database can include privileges that apply to **any** database or to the cluster resource, and can inherit from roles in other databases as well as the `admin` database.

So, I assume `user1` was not created in `admin` database. Most likely you created it `test` database, which is the default. Then above limitations apply.

Create user in `admin` database and grant required roles:

```
use admin
db.runCommand( {
       createUser: "user1",
       pwd: "secret",
       roles: [ "readWrite" ]
} )
```

or

```
db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand(...)
```

This user can create any database, and he can write into any database.

Every database provides [built-In Roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/) `read`, `readWrite`, `dbOwner`, `dbAdmin`, `userAdmin`.

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
use admin
db.runCommand( {
       createUser: "user1",
       pwd: "secret",
       roles: [ { role: "dbOwner", db: "db1" } ]
} )
```

This commands creates the user and grant `dbOwner` of database `db1`. He can write into database `db1`, he cannot create or read any other database.

Comment: For example, if I have a user with privileges to create a database and this user can see only his database and that created by him. Is it possible to have this scenario on MongoDB?

Comment: No, it is not possible. A user is created in a database, thus you **first** must create the **database** (or at least the name of this database must be known beforehand), afterwards you can create a user in this database. If you create the user in `admin` database (or more precisely grant privilege `readWrite` scoped to `admin`), then this user can create any database.

Comment: Thank you, @Wenfried for your clarification and great explanation.